# Flask-Bootstrap quick_form thinks form passed in from render_template is undefined

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, jinja2

I'm trying to render a WTF form with Flask-Bootstrap `quick_form`.  However, I get an error that `form` is undefined, even though I pass it in with `render_template`.  Why isn't this working?

```
File "/home/eron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html", line 190, in template
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

File "/home/eron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 397, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form

class NameForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Login', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/base', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('base'))

    return render_template('base.html', form=form)
```

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import  "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

<div class="col-md-3">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is nearly 2 years late, but I've had a similar issue and thought I would like to share. 
You can change 'form' to 'blogform'. It seems that Jinja is confused with the 'Form' module that you were importing from Flask-WTF:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
```

You simply need to change your variable name to something else other than 'form', for instance 'blogform':

```
@app.route('/base', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    blogform = NameForm()

    if blogform.validate_on_submit():
        name = blogform.name.data
        session['name'] = blogform.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('base'))

    return render_template('base.html', blogform=blogform)
```

Since the variable passed in render_template is now changed to blogform, in your HTML file, change it accordingly as well:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import  "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

<div class="col-md-3">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(blogform) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You wrote: 
`class NameForm(Form):` 
and then 
`return render_template('base.html', form=form)`

Firstly try to change `form = form` to `Form = Form`

If this doesn't working try to remove `form = NameForm()` and try again.

Comment: what's the logic behind that? That would mean I would be passing the class and not the object itself, wouldn't it?

Answer (score -3):

Remove
    {% import  "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %} from the div tag and put it at the end of it